# multi level hierarchy access control table

Tags: mysql, database-design, acl, access-control

i am having some trouble implementing acl. i have the following already

**table: users**
id

**table: roles**
id
role

**table: user_roles**
id
user_id
role_id

**table: permissions**
id
permissions

**table: role_permissions**
id
role_id
permission_id

**table: user_permissions**
id
user_id
permission_id

when a user logs, roles are fetched and based on those roles, permissions are fetched then stored on a permissions array for later use.

while the above works fine, the addition of locations and stores got me confused.

**table: locations**
id
location

**table: stores**
id 
store

so, basically a user can have a general role assigned: 
global admin, global personnel
can also become location admin or personnel
then can also become store admin or personnel

store are located in a location
locations are managed by global office

now, how do i integrate locations and stores with the existing access control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect `Store` and `User`. `User` and all the permissions related to a particular store can be stored here.

There is a Ternary relationship between, `Store`, `User` and `Permission`
Now, Store and User have a many to many relation. In the association table, `Store_User`, you can link the `Permission` table. This will make sure that **each store has a specific set of permission for each user**.

This should explain more:

[image]